# Pointer value changing across function call

Tags: c, linux, pointers, kernel

I have the following structures in the kernel

```
struct state {
    /* Current algorithm iteration */
    int tune_id;
    /* Thread id */
    pid_t tid;
#ifndef __KERNEL__
    /* Paths */
    char *stats_path;
    char *budget_path;
    char *controller_path;
#endif  /* __KERNEL__ */
    int budget;
    /* Stats */
    struct statistics prev_stats;
    struct parameters current_params;
    u64 cur_time;
    /* Algorithm specific data */
    void *data;
};

struct tuning {
    struct algorithm *algorithm;
    struct state *state;
    struct energy energy;
};
```

I've defined a function `tune()` as follows:

```
void tune(struct task_struct *task) {
    struct statistics stats;
    struct state *state;
    get_current_stats(&stats);
    state = task->tuning.state;

    get_current_params(&state->current_params);
    compute_energy(&stats, state);
}
```

The other functions are defined as:

```
void get_current_params(struct parameters *params)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "get_current_params: parameters:0x%X\n", (unsigned int) params);
    params->cpu_frequency_MHZ = (cpufreq_get(0) + 500) / 1000;
    params->mem_frequency_MHZ = (memfreq_get() + 500) / 1000;
}

void compute_energy(struct statistics *stats, struct state *state)
{
    struct statistics *diffs;
    struct frontier *frontier;
    u64 energy_budget;
    int threshold;

    int i,j;
    struct configuration s;
    struct configuration emin;

#ifdef TIMING
    u64 ns;
    ns = get_thread_time();
 #endif

#ifdef DEBUG
#ifdef __KERNEL__
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "compute_energy: parameters:0x%X\n", (unsigned int) &state->current_params);
#endif  /* __KERNEL__ */
#endif
}
```

When I call `tune()`, the output is as follows:

```
[    7.160139] get_current_params: parameters:0xBF396BA0
[    7.160298] compute_energy: parameters:0xBF396B98
```

I don't understand why the addresses differ by `0x8`.
This in turn causes a divide by 0 exception in the kernel since the `struct parameters` seems to have values of `0` instead of what was initialized by `get_current_params`

Why is it that the address of the member `current_params` of `struct state` changes across function calls?

**Update**:
I've verified that this bug only occurs for PID 0.
Looking at `include/linux/init_task.h`, I see that PID 0 is statically initialized. This is the only difference I could find between PID 0 and the other tasks. Could this somehow be responsible for the issue I'm having?

Comment: I have updated the question with the functions. They don't really do much before the point of printing and so I presumed that they wouldn't be necessary to add.

Comment: The 2 functions you mentioned are passed 2 different parameters. `get_current_params()`  received a `struct state->struct parameters` while `compute_enregy()` received a `struct statistics` parameter. Clearly 2 different parameters, hence 2 different locations. The second parameter is `struct state`, still different than `struct state-> struct parameters`.

Comment: I agree that different parameters are being passed, but I would argue that the member being printed is still the same..or am I somehow wrong in assuming that?

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see, you are right in that both addresses should be the same. So there can only be one option: task information changes in the kernel in the meanwhile.

Considering this snippet of your code:

```
void tune(struct task_struct *task) {
    ...
    struct state *state;
    ...
    state = task->tuning.state;
```

You are managing two structs over which you may have no control (you should check that):

```
(*task): struct task_struct
```

and

```
(*task->tuning.state): struct state
```

So when in `tune()` you call

```
get_current_params(&state->current_params);
compute_energy(&stats, state);
```

something could happen between both `printk` functions, so there is where I think you have to put your focus in.
Try saving `task->tuning.state` before the call to `get_current_params()` so you could check that it continues to be the same value after call to `compute_energy()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You have a good point! Context switches may be occuring between the two calls. I will test this out and update the original question accordingly

Comment: I created pointers to reference the current task and passed those references around instead of referencing `task->...` each time. This *should* help me avoid the complexities introduced by context switches. However, I'm still running into the same problem